# Rust equivalent for a Javascript map over a 2D vector iterator

Tags: dictionary, rust, compiler-errors, iterator, dynamic-programming

I am new to Rust. I am learning, by trying to port the code shown in Javascript (in https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk) to Rust. While trying to code the function shown at around https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk?t=10912 starting with the for-loop on line 4, I am stuck with Rust as follows.

In Javascript on line 8, we have:

```
const targetWays = suffixWays.map(way => [word, ...way])
```

In Rust, I am trying to write this as:

```
let target_ways = suffix_ways.into_iter().map(|way| way.insert(0, word_bank[i].clone())).collect::<Vec<Vec<String>>>();
```

However, I get a compile time error

```
value of type `std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=()>`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `way.insert` modifies `way` in place and doesn't return anything. change your closure to `|way| { way.insert(…); way }` so that it returns the modified `way`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vec::insert` returns `()`, because it simply modifies the vec in place. So the closure: `|way| way.insert(0, word_bank[i].clone())` has the type `fn(Vec<String>) -> ()`.

Instead, you probably want something like this:

```rust
let target_ways: Vec<_> = suffix_ways.into_iter().map(|way| {
  way.insert(0, word_bank[i].clone());
  way
}).collect();
```

FWIW, inserting to the start of a `Vec` can be quite costly, since it reallocates the underlying memory and copies all the elements over. It's generally cheaper to push to the end of a vec, and reverse at the end if you have to. This is especially true you know the size of the vec in advance (and so can create it with `Vec::with_capacity` to allocate all the memory in one go ahead of time).

Though if you're just learning, feel free to ignore this and just get on with building something cool :)

Comment: The semantics are completely different than the JS ones which create a new array (~vec) for each item though. As such it seems... sub-optimal to consume the existing vector (of vectors) only to re-create *the exact same one* with new items prepended to the sub-vectors. This would make a lot more sense as a loop over `&mut suffix_ways` IMO: the `map` is not used to actually convert anything, so it is the wrong operation.

Comment: Thank you both. @Masklinn, do you have an example code to illustrate a more optimised way? Sorry, my Rust skills are too beginner-level to find more efficient alternatives.

Comment: @xtremebytes just iterate the source vector using a `for` loop (or a `for_each`) and update the sub-vectors in-place using `insert` the way it's already done. If you're going to insert from the start a lot you may also want to consider `VecDeque`: `Vec` is O(n) for head insertion as it needs to move all the existing elements to make room. `VecDeque` has cheaper insertion (and removal) at the head *but* it's overall less efficient, so it depends on the work load.

Comment: Indeed, the closure was not returning anything. Thanks for pointing out as did @jmb in my original post above. However, returning the way seems impossible for the block of code I am working with due to ownership constraints. I have to return `way.clone()` instead.

@Masklinn, thank you. I will try the VecDeque.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, taking into account the fact that the closure must return some value and without using `VecDeque`, here is the code for the function.

```
fn all_construct(target: String, word_bank: &mut Vec<String>) -> Vec<Vec<String>> {
    if target.is_empty() {
        return vec![vec![]];
    }

    let mut result:Vec<Vec<String>> = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..word_bank.len() {
        let search = &word_bank[i];
        if target.starts_with(search) {
            let suffix = target.chars().skip(search.len()).collect();
            let mut suffix_ways = all_construct(suffix, word_bank);
            let target_ways:Vec<_> = suffix_ways.iter_mut().map(|way| {
                way.insert(0, word_bank[i].clone());
                way.clone()
            }).collect::<Vec<Vec<String>>>();
            result.extend(target_ways);
        }
    }

    result
}
```

Feel free to suggest improvements.